# How can I block all IPv6 Adresses starting like this 2a01:598:xxx in my .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, ip, blocking

How Can I block all IP Adresses that start like this 2a01:598: in my htaccess file?

I tried:

```
Deny from 2a01:598::/28
```

and i also tried it like this:

```
Deny from 2a01:598::
```

But it doesnt work? What am I doing wrong?

My wordpress website is running on shared Hosting.

Looking forward to your answers.

Comment: What version of Apache are you on?

Comment: We could and should assume 2.4, as 2.2 has been EOL since January 2018.

Answer (score 0):

As described in Apache 2.4 [Access Control](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html):

> The `Allow`, `Deny`, and `Order` directives, provided by `mod_access_compat`,
>   are deprecated and will go away in a future version. You should avoid
>   using them, and avoid outdated tutorials recommending their use.

Use [`Require`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require), instead:

```
Require not ip 2a01:598::/28
```

This should work in the `.htaccess` context, unless limited by an [`AllowOverride`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride) in the server configuration.

Comment: I just tried it to block my own ipv6 adress. But even if i use the described code i can access my website. 

If I block my own ipv4 range it is working just fine. BUt not with my Ipv6?

Comment: Are you sure the connection is made over IPv6?

Comment: Yes if i go to whatismyip.com my ipv6 and my ipv4 adress is shown. And if block my exact ipv6 adress i cant connect. But if i only block like this 2a01:598::/28 im still able to visit my site?

Comment: Is there a way to block all ipv6 connections to my website and only allow ipv4 adresses?

Comment: The `2a01:598::/28` refers to range from 
`2a01:590:0:0:0:0:0:0` to `2a01:59f:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff`. Are you positive your IP is on that range?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean. I have  list of ips that visited my site. All of the ips started with 2a01:598:xxxx? Maybe I can send  you the list?

Comment: That's not necessary. Just trying to rule some obvious reasons out.